# Pausing the execution of the script using a customize alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have overridden the default alert box with a custom dialog box.
But I want the script to be paused until the cancel button on the dialog box is clicked.
How to achieve it using javascript or jquery ?

**P.S.** : I am trying to make a dialog box which has the same functionality as an alert box.

Comment: override your custom dialog box with the default alert box...

Answer (score 1):

You can not write blocking code in javascript as it is single threaded and runs on the same thread as the UI, see here: [Blocking "wait" function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066933/blocking-wait-function-in-javascript)

You could do it via callbacks or events that get fired when your custom alert box gets closed.

```
function CustomAlert(message, callback)
{
    alert(message);
    callback();
}

function CodeWhichGetsBlocked()
{
    DoSomething();
    CustomAlert("continue?", function() {
        DoSomething();
    });
}
```

Comment: If I override the alert with a dialog the callback will be executed without waiting for me to click the cancel button.
I want the script to be paused until the cancel button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, you have to execute the callback when the cancel button is clicked. I just gave an example.

Answer (score 0):

I will use dynamic HTML.

```
var $divAlert = $("<div>Are you sure going to next step?</div>");

$divAlert.dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function(){
                //Your Code/Logic goes here
            },
                    "Cencel": function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
        }
});
```

you can also customize in temrs of design your dialog just add class.

like,

```
dialogClass: "MyDialog"
```

Comment: Boss !
I am trying to make the dialog similar to alert... i.e. The execution of the script should be paused when the dialog is appeared.